# Form wrapping - Bootstrap

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have developed several forms for one of my client website. These forms will be connecting with a database. I did front-end part only for the website. These are the forms.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control services-main-menu">
     <option>Select category*</option>
     <option value="1">Home services</option>
     <option value="2">Financial services</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
 <div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title*">
 <div class="actual-price">
 <small class="meta">70 characters left</small>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Description*"></textarea>
<div class="actual-price">
<small class="meta">4000 characters left</small>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I just want to know that should I need to wrap my all forms using `<form> </form>` tag? or just let it as this way? This might be an issue for the back-end developer?

Comment: Well that depends on what it is supposed to be used for. _“These forms will be connecting with a database”_ could mean anything.

Comment: If forms will connecting with a database when you should used `<form></form>` .. There is reference of form in bootstrap : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: So in here, I used two col-md-12 divs. Should I wrap all divs using <form> tag?

Answer (score 1):

Try to always use form tags. They have special CSS from BS:3. I some sittuations page/element can crushy viusal part of web/template.
I suggest to use .row clas before .col-md-12. That prevents also to situation what i'm talking about higher.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to store this data in a database, probably you're going to send this data using GET or POST. Both ways you'll be using form tags (and a *method* attribute). So, yes, embrace the fields that will be sent to the database with a form tag.

Answer (score 0):

It will work without `<form>`, but you should keep some standards. You will need it the following situations:

- You need it if you want to execute a traditional (ie. non-AJAX) form post.
- You need it you want to capture the "submit" event programmatically.
- You need it in order for mobile Safari to show the "Go" button on the keyboard.-
- You need it if you want to programmatically "reset" a form (ie. call reset()).
- It makes generic form serialization easier (since it groups input fields).
- You need it if you want to post files without the modern file API.
- You need it if you have to segregate fields with the same name.

> Writing a form consists of several steps, which can be performed in
>   any order: writing the user interface, implementing the server-side
>   processing, and configuring the user interface to communicate with the
>   server.

Sources: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html, https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2435-are-html-form-tags-required-to-display-form-input-controls.htm